# Is there a way to specify access modifiers for primary constructor in C#?

Tags: c#, .net-core

Use Case:
I am trying to create a discriminated class (sort of)

```
public class SomeResult<TResult>(TResult? result,Dictionary<string,string>? errors)  
{
   public TResult? Result => result;
   public Dictionary<string, string>? Errors => errors;
}
```

If Result is null, then it is a failure. In that case Errors will not be null.
If Result is not null, then it is a success. In that case Errors will be null.

To enforce that, I would like to create two factory methods and `make the constructor private.`

```
public static SomeResult<TResult> GetSuccess(TResult result) => new SomeResult(result,null);

public static SomeResult<TResult> GetFailure(Dictionary<string,string> errors) => new SomeResult(null,errors);
```

Is there a way to do it using primary constructor? The problem is that the access modifier applies to the class and not the constructor.

Comment: Under [Drawbacks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-12.0/primary-constructors): *"There is no way to express separate accessibility of the class and the primary constructor. An example is when public constructors all delegate to one private "build-it-all" constructor. If necessary, syntax could be proposed for that later."*

Comment: Thanks. If you post it as an answer, I will mark it as accepted and close.

Comment: Could you elaborate how would you use those two factory methods in the code actually ? What benefits it gives you? Im just curious.

Comment: Factory methods ensure that only one field is set by a dev- thus the result is either Success or Failure. If I leave the constructor accessible, both fields could be accidently set without any error at the compilation stage.

Comment: The same thing could be accomplished by implementing 2 constructors. One takes `TResult result` (not nullable unless success actually can be null), and the other takes `Dictionary<string,string>` (again, not nullable because failure needs to report errors). This, too, deviates from primary constructors, which just aren't a good fit for this any way you slice it. I would even go so far as to say that primary constructors are more of an edge case and the way Visual Studio is pushing them on us with code style suggestions is wrong.

Comment: Factory methods add clarity to the code reader ("GetSuccess", "GetFailure") with the same number of lines. I avoid multiple constructors, esp since you can have default argument. In case the constructor arguments require significant preprocessing, I factor them out in the code/ factory. This is particularly   true if the preprocessing is async.

Comment: Primary constructors are syntactic sugar that makes the code less cluttered - much like extension methods. I find them particularly useful in the DI situations.